# Google Cloud Datastore gives 401 error response code

Tags: angular, google-cloud-datastore

I want to build a simple rest API using Google Cloud Datastore and I can't access my data

First, I am new with Google Cloud Platform but this is not going to stop me until I find a solution on how to make a rest API call with Google Cloud Datastore.

I use Angular 4 in as front end and I want to make a simple HTTP request.

## This is my data in Google Cloud Datastore

[image]

## This is my api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';




@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  private apiUrl1 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  private apiUrl2= 'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-test:runQuery?key=dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsds';

  data: any = {};

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  getData1() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl1)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());  <====== this works
  }

  getData2() {
    const body = {
      "query": {}
    };

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl2, body)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()); <====== this dont works
  }

}
```

## I have this error

> POST
>   https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-test:runQuery?key=1b169abfa8b87ewewqewewqewqewqewqewqe
>   401 ()

Plese some expert tell me if I can access Google cloud datastore with rest API
If yes why I have error 401 and why I need OAuth2

> "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential.
>   Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid
>   authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",↵
>   "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"↵  }↵}↵"

How the users can access my data. Some data is going to be publicly available

Any example how to access Cloud datastore with rest API is going to help us.
I search the entire internet there is nothing . 0 Youtube videos 
And all documentations is with App engine . i use Firebase hosting - angular 4 and for the queries i want cloud datastore

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - API keys will not work with Cloud Datastore APIs. You should instead use `OAuth 2.0` access tokens from either user credentials or service accounts.

### [API key limitations](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

Based on the [API key documentation for Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys), only the following 4 Cloud services support API keys and Cloud Datastore is not one of them. They are usually only used with APIs which do not require access to private user data.

- [Google Cloud Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/)
- [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/)
- [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)
- [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/)

### [Google Cloud Platform supported authentication mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/)

In addition to API keys, GCP supports authentication using user account credentials and service accounts. They are [explained in detail here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/).

### [Using `OAuth 2.0` to invoke Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Once you have either a user account credential or a service account credentials, using `OAuth 2.0` you need to obtain the access token. The [process is described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps). I did find [these steps specific to javascript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#authorized-access) which I feel might be of most help to your use case.

The example in that page again mentions API key (which will not work for your use case) and I could not find any Angular specific example which uses service accounts.  If you're using Node.js, there is a [`google-auth` library for Node.js](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs) which takes care of all the authentication when using service accounts. The library also supports [`Application Default Credentials`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).

### Passing `OAuth 2.0` credentials

Once you have obtained the `OAuth 2.0` access token (aka bearer token), you can pass it using one of these 3 query parameters in the Cloud Datastore API request:

- `access_token`
- `oauth_token`
- `bearer_token`

### Example using command line

```
echo '{gqlQuery: {queryString: "SELECT * FROM Task"}}' | http POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME:runQuery?bearer_token=YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
```

If you have `gcloud` installed you can get the current access token using:

```
# Prints the access token
gcloud auth print-access-token
# Use the access token to send the request
echo '{gqlQuery: {queryString: "SELECT * FROM Task"}}' | http POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_NAME:runQuery?bearer_token=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
```

Comment: Thanx for your help Tuxdude